# Start-Process and the Stop Parsing (--%) parameter

Tags: powershell, escaping, start-process

I am having trouble getting the `--%` parameter to work as expected. My `$TaskParams` variable has the character `'<'` which is interpreted as a redirection by powershell, therefore needs to be escaped.

However the following does not work:

```
$CreateTask = Start-Process PowerShell.exe "$ScriptLocation --% $TaskParams" -Wait -PassThru
```

Without the `--%`, and when I manually remove any `'<'` characters, it works:

```
$CreateTask = Start-Process PowerShell.exe "$ScriptLocation $TaskParams" -Wait -PassThru
```

error received:

```
 Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'--%'.
```

note: I am using PS 5.0

Am I using the `--%` parameter wrong?  Any help or pointers is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need `Start-Process powershell.exe`? Just run your script with the needed parameters.

Comment: Can't get it to execute anything without Start-Process. Can you lay out what you had in mind? thx!

Comment: Why do you need to spin up a new PowerShell process and use `Start-Process`? Just run the script.

Comment: because i am running from a seperate .ps1

Comment: You can run a .ps1 file directly from another. Just put the script name in the other script and run it. I do this all the time!

Comment: Wow cool, didnt realize this was doable! But now I'm getting errors passing in my parameters, like so: C:\Scripts\PathToPS1 "-description 'testdesc' -title 'testtitle'" . Is that how its done?

Comment: Don't quote the parameters like that. Just put the parameters and arguments on the script's command line, just as if you were typing the command at the PowerShell prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to spin up a new copy of powershell.exe or use `Start-Process` to run a script from within another script. Just put the script command and its parameters as a line from within the other script. For example, suppose you have script2.ps1:

```
param(
  [String] $Name
)
Write-Host "Hello, $Name"
```

Now suppose you also have script1.ps1:

```
Write-Host "This is script1.ps1"
.\Script2.ps1 -Name "Bill Stewart"
Write-Host "script1.ps1 is finished"
```

If you now run script1.ps1:

```
PS C:\> .\Script1.ps1
This is script1.ps1
Hello, Bill Stewart
script1.ps1 is finished
```

Comment: Wow so simple and aesthetic . thank you @Bill_Stewart !

Comment: Now this has me thinking. What if I had multiple parameters and wanted them in one variable. Let me see if I can get that working now..

Comment: @Quanda if you want to put them in a variable, make them a `[hashtable]`, not a string, then use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) to call like this: `.\Script1.ps1 @myParams` (where `$myParams` is the hashtable variable).

Comment: This shows some of the value of asking a good question. The question was not really about quoting at all; it was really this: "How do I call one PowerShell script from within another?"

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help. My original question was actually how to escape characters like '<' but it turned out I was doing this the hard way and it didn't need to be escaped at all. Should I change the title of my question?

Comment: Is there a way to handle errors here?                 `$CreateTask = C:\Scripts\Pathto.ps1 @CreateTaskParams` Would a `Try{}Catch{}` block work?

Comment: @Quanda `try{}` it and see!

Answer (score 4):

The stop-parsing symbol `--%` only works when calling executables directly or with the call operator `&`; it's not for use when calling PowerShell scripts / functions / cmdlets.

Comment: Ah well that explains it. Would there be another way to escape PowerShell commands or expressions (in this case, the redirection < character) within a variable when calling a powershell script?

Comment: @Quanda `Start-Process` has an `-ArgumentList` parameter, which you should be using to pass arguments. You can try to send them in as a single string, but you can also split them up as an array: `-ArgumentList 'arg1','arg2','argument three','a4'`.

Comment: but could I escape the PS system expressions (i.e '<', ':') if one of the arguments contains one of those characters?

Comment: @Quanda you may not need to. Try it first.

Comment: Can you show an example using the ArgumentList as array with named parameters? would it be something like this?  `-ArgumentList '-arg1Name $arg1Value', '-arg2Name $arg2Value' `

Comment: @Quanda think about it as though it were invoking from the windows command line. It doesn't know about named arguments. `-ParamName value` looks like 2 arguments because it's separated by a space. So in argument list I would make them 2 different elements. `-ArgumentList '-ParamName','value'`. I would consider a single element containing a space to be used as though you had wrapped it in `"` on the command line (so that it would be treated as a single parameter).

Comment: cant get this to work :(  is there an alternative to `Start-Process` that is recommended to call a powershell script and pass it a list of named parameters?

Comment: @Quanda as Bill_Stewart asked in his comment, why not just call the script with the parameters you want? `>` isn't going to be misinterpreted that way as long as it's quoted.

Comment: I didn't understand how do you call the script without start-process keyword? i need this to get executed within another script

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use `Start-Process` you could encode the argument, and run it as such. I use something similar to this when elevating past UAC:

```
$Code = ". '$ScriptLocation' $TaskParams"
$Encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code))

Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList "-EncodedCommand",$Encoded -Wait -PassThru
```

I'm fairly certain that would accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: I love `-EncodedCommand`! This is a great way to accomplish the desired outcome, as long as the issue is not caused by PowerShell misintepreting the character (I'm not actually certain where it's causing the snag in this instance as I just haven't had a chance to).